# Wifi disconnects randomly then says "Cant connect to this network"

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router, network-adapter

I have a [Slaxry Wireless 150M PCI-E PCI Express Card Adapter Cordless WIFI Network Wireless LAN Ethernet NIC with External and Detachable Antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M0TYJXK).

Sometimes randomly, it just disconnects from my router. I check my available connections and they're all there. I try connecting to my main network and it says `Can’t Connect To This Network`.

The only fix that I've found for this is to either Restart, sleep then turn on, or shut down then turn on. I've tried turning the wifi off, then back and try again but that is no use.

I've tried other methods such as disabling the network adapter in the control panel and re-enabling it. If I do this it still says cannot connect to this network.

This only works on my computer. My phone and laptop is always connected to the internet even when my computer disconnects.

If you have any questions, just ask me. Any help is appreciated!

```
My specs:

Windows 10 Pro
i5-4590
GTX 1650
12GB DDR3 RAM
1TB HDD
PCIe 150 Mbps wireless wifi card
```

Comment: Does this problem occur on any other devices? Try it on your phone or a laptop.

Comment: @jitter this only happens on my computer.

Comment: Have you checked that the PCI card is seated firmly? A loose or poorly soldered connection can cause temporary disconnection. Also, when does the issue occur? Is it after resuming from hibernation? After a large appliance or microwave oven turn on (or off)? Has there been an AC mains "glitch" (i.e., lights blink)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try opening command prompt as administrator and typing the following?

`netsh winsock reset` and select <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`netsh int ip reset` and select <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`ipconfig /release` and select <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`ipconfig /renew` and select <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`ipconfig /flushdns` and select <kbd>Enter</kbd>.